# VUE.JS after parsing trough the JSON getting wrong output

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I did [GET] method using Axios. Everything is working fine, when I want to output i get this kind of thing:

http://prntscr.com/mpey70

This is my JS with HTML and VUE code on how I am trying to output it:

HTML, VUE:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <p>Casuals</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <div v-bind:key="realsub.id+1"  v-for="realsub in subnavreal">
                                      <div v-if="nav.linkTitle == 'Male'">
                                            <li><router-link :to="{ path: whiteSpace(realsub.male.casual) }">{{JSON.realsub.male.casual}}</router-link></li>
                                    </div>

                                        <div v-if="nav.linkTitle == 'Female'"></div>
                                            <li><router-link :to="{ path: whiteSpace(realsub.female.casual) }">{{realsub.female.casual}}</router-link></li>
                                        </div>

                                </ul>

                            </div>
```

And this is Related JS code:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import uuid from 'uuid';
export default {
    name: 'navigation',
    data(){
        return{
            subnavreal: []

        }
    },
    props: ["navigation"],
    methods:{
        whiteSpace(a){

            console.log(a);
        }
    },
    async created(){

        axios.get('/products.json')
        .then(res => this.subnavreal = res.data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));


    }

}
</script>
```

What I want to display is only the name of that object, for example: "Hoodies"

Any solutions? :)

Comment: You have to traverse the arrays and objects to get to the data you need, for example `Hoodies[3].Image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are printing the entire Response. You can use the Object.keys() to print the keys.

```
 let user = {
       name: "tom",
       age: 20
       }
```

If you want to print the keys [name, age] use `Object.keys(user)`